# Fiddler adds space after colon

Tags: http, fiddler

I am making a request like so in Fiddler2

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: asdf.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 0
Key=asdf:qwer
```

When I click <kbd>Execute</kbd>, Fiddler edits the last line to read:

```
Key=asdf: qwer
```

Note the additional space.

Why is this happening and could it cause problems with my request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [**RFC 2616, 4.2 Message Headers**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2):

> Each header field consists
> of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
> are case-insensitive. **The field value MAY be preceded by any amount
> of LWS, though a single SP is preferred**.

> [...]

> The field-content does not include any leading or trailing LWS:
> linear white space occurring before the first non-whitespace
> character of the field-value or after the last non-whitespace
> character of the field-value. Such leading or trailing LWS MAY be
> removed without changing the semantics of the field value. Any LWS
> that occurs between field-content MAY be replaced with a single SP
> before interpreting the field value or forwarding the message
> downstream.

In other words: leading whitespace is to be ignored for the field value, and a space is even preferred. When you *do* want to send a space, you'll have to [quote the string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-17): `Some-Header: " foo"`.

So it's nice of Fiddler to display (and probably send) it like that, though a custom HTTP server that doesn't expect a space there is faulty and should be repaired.

As for your comment regarding the "invalid header name" error the server returns: an HTTP header is defined as such:

> ```
> message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
> ```

```
field-name     = token
field-value    = [...]
```

As you can see, `field-name` can only exist of [`token`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-17), which does not include `=` (as that is a `separator`).

So the header name `Key=asdf` you use is invalid and the server throws a `400 Bad Request` because of malformed syntax. The more specific `Invalid header name` you claim to get, sounds like you're running your site in IIS. Change the `=` to `-` for example, and you'll see it'll work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually having issues with my request (returning a `400 - invalid header name`) - could it be that it is interpreting `Key=asdf:` as as a key and `qwer` as a value?

Comment: No, `field-name` (the "header" you're trying to set) can only exist of `token` (see RFC), which does not include `=`.

Comment: @Eric no, the `field-name` OP tries to send is `Key=asdf`, on which I would expect the server to return a `400`.